# How should I design this Database + Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I Started of thinking that I would just manually entering in my data through ms sql for a project I am working on(this is a prototype/ proof of concept project) but after designing the database I see it's just going to be a pain and probably won't save me any time, so I am going to develop a form that I can fill out and have it save to the database.

When I was thinking of manual entering data I designed my database like this

Product table has one Country and a Country Table can have many Products.

I was trying to make sure there would be no typos as I would have to hook it up to an existing Country vs just having a field call Country in the products table and open it up to typos.

Now since I am going to enter it in through a form, I am wondering is there really a point to have this separate table in this case?

I was thinking of instead put it in the product table but in my C# code create an enum called Country with the valid Countries list. So this should stop any typos as I would probably have it as a dropdown and if it can't convert into the enum it would fail.

I think in this case it makes more sense to do this versus having the separate table called Country with an PK and Name field.

I wanted to hear other peoples thoughts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate table which uses a non-sensical key (which could be an enum internally or an identity column) and a display value is the best design for the following reasons:

1) If a country name changes (which is a not-infrequent event recently) or is added, you won't have to recompile.

2) If your application is used in different countries, they will almost certainly have different spellings for other countries, in which case it is much easier to update the database than produce a different version of your application for each country it is sold in.

Comment: Well my thinking is this. Say I have Canada and U.S. If a user would choose Canada. It could very well be that I might have some special condition if Canada is choosen. So I am looking at either hard-coding == "Canada" or having a Enum with the countries. So that's why I am thinking I would probably need to recompile the code either way but I would have to now update it in 2 places. With the language thing I total agree with you on that but I know this thing I am making will be probably only ever be for English countries(it is very specific to country data).

Comment: In that case, I would definitely go with an ENum. What you could do later if you need to provide different or changed data later is have an optional lookup list in the database that would be keyed by your enum values. Descriptions in this table could override your default names, which would give you both flexibility and the functionality that you need.

Comment: Ya it such a hard call for me. On one side I think it is good to have it like you said in the separate table but right now I just see it being one field(name field) and I think that is overkill to put that in a separate table. If I had more fields then I think it would be a different story. I think regardless though I would need the enum as there probably will be separate business logic for each country.